# Is it possible to convert a If statement recurrence to a for loop?

Tags: c#

So I'm new to coding and I'm working on C# to understand the basics.

Basically, I want to implement my code below in a loop to minimize duplication. What type of loop can I use and how can I implement?

```
if (Counters[0] == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("3 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[2]);
}
else if (Counters[0] == 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[1]);
}
else if (Counters[0] == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("5 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[0]);
}

if (Counters[1] == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("3 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[5]);
}
else if (Counters[1] == 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[4]);
}
else if (Counters[1] == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("5 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[3]);
}

if (Counters[2] == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("3 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[8]);
}
else if (Counters[2] == 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("4 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[7]);
}
else if (Counters[2] == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("5 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[6]);
}
```

Comment: I dont think you want to *convert* those ifs to loops, rather execute the ifs *in* a loop

Comment: It's not the c# basics you should work on, but the logic on what you want to implement. Maybe you should try to describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works but is asking for improvements ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: All you need to do is find a way to calculate all those numbers from the counter index. The string contains the value read from `Counters` so there's no reason to hard-code it. The `PayCombos` index is clearly a function of the Counters index and content

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to check each member of the array, either with a `foreach`:

```
int[] Counters = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

foreach (int counter in Counters)
{
    if (counter == 3) Console.WriteLine("3 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[2]);
    else if (counter == 4) Console.WriteLine("4 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[1]);
    else if (counter == 5) Console.WriteLine("5 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[0]);
}
```

Or a `for`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Counters.Length; i++)
{
    if (Counters[i] == 3) Console.WriteLine("3 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[2]);
    else if (Counters[i] == 4) Console.WriteLine("4 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[1]);
    else if (Counters[i] == 5) Console.WriteLine("5 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

A loop is perfect when you want to repeat an operation. You're obviously repeating the 'counter check' part of your code for multiple counters, so it's an ideal candidate for using a loop.

The simplest way to implement, in my opinion, is to think of encapsulating the repeated logic in a function, and isolating that logic from the 'thing' against which it is operating.

In this case you are operating on a counter from a list, and you're checking the values. I'd suggest writing a simple function that does the checking against a counter (i.e. remove the list/array), and then call that function inside a loop.

So

```
void checkCounter(counter)
{    
    if (counter == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[8]);
    }
    else if (counter == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("4 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[7]);
    }
    else if (counter == 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("5 OAK A pays" + PayCombos[6]);
    }    
}
```

Then looping through your counters is as simple as

```
foreach (int counter in Counters)
{
    checkCounter(counter)
}
```